# hide_empty categories in Woocommerce not working

Tags: woocommerce, categories

I use this shortcode to display subcategories, and it's working fine.
But i would like to hide empty categories, and hide_empty is not working.

```
function woocommerce_subcats_by_id( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'parent_cat_id' => '',
    ), $atts ) );
 
    $idbyid = get_term_by('id', $parent_cat_id, 'product_cat');
    $product_cat_ID = $idbyid->term_id;
      
    $args = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'child_of' => $product_cat_ID,
        'hide_empty' => true
        
    );
    $subcats = get_terms($args);
    $content = '<ul class="woodmart-woocommerce-layered-nav">';
      foreach ($subcats as $sc) {
        $link = get_term_link( $sc->slug, $sc->taxonomy );
          $content .= '<li class="woodmart-woocommerce-layered-nav"><a class="layered-nav-link" href="'. $link .'"><span class="swatch-inner"><span class="layer-term-name">'.$sc->name.'</span></span></a></li>';
      }
    $content .= '</ul>';
    return $content;
}
add_shortcode( 'show_sub', 'woocommerce_subcats_by_id' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you haven't wrote the beginning of your function. I presume it is like this

```
function woocommerce_subcats_by_id($atts){

    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
          'parent_cat_id' => '',
    ), $atts ) );
 
    $idbyid = get_term_by('id', $parent_cat_id, 'product_cat');
    $product_cat_ID = $idbyid->term_id;
      
    $args = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'child_of' => $product_cat_ID,
        'hide_empty' => true
        
    );
    $subcats = get_terms($args);
    $content = '<ul class="woodmart-woocommerce-layered-nav">';
      foreach ($subcats as $sc) {
        $link = get_term_link( $sc->slug, $sc->taxonomy );
          $content .= '<li class="woodmart-woocommerce-layered-nav"><a class="layered-nav-link" href="'. $link .'"><span class="swatch-inner"><span class="layer-term-name">'.$sc->name.'</span></span></a></li>';
      }
    $content .= '</ul>';
    return $content;
}
add_shortcode( 'show_sub', 'woocommerce_subcats_by_id' );
```

And It hides the empty categories.

Comment: Hi @Unce Still it does not hide the empty categories. I think I forgot to paste the function in my first post.

Comment: Hi, can you please edit your post that it includes the beginning of function. Also might be that you have other plugin enabled that filters your query.

Comment: I have tried to disable all plugins and used a default theme but it keep up showing the empty subcategories.
Maybe I need to place a COUNT in the code somewhere?
```($subcats->count > 0)```

Comment: Are you sure your categories are empty?

Comment: Yes, we have a couple of empty categories. But they show up :-(

Comment: I found it! there were articles in this category, but they were not in stock. Thanks for your help!